# How to host vuejs/firebase apps on 3rd party host

Tags: firebase, vuejs2

I'm just starting out on firebase and found out its an amazing service for managing your back-ends and database. I am considering building an app with vuejs and firebase but I want to get some clarifications on the hosting part first. I see that I can deploy and host the app on firebase, but with the issue of having that 'my-app/firebase.com' domain structure which I don't want. My question is,how can I build the app with vuejs and Firebase and then deploy and host  the app on a 3rd party host like hostgator or digital ocean so I can have my personalized domain 'my-app.com', whilst still using firebase to manage my back-ends.
References to any helpful resources will be appreciated

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic In addition, your question is far too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the hosting of files and tying those hosted files to a domain name.

When you host a site on Firebase Hosting, it automatically creates two domains for you: `projectname.firebaseapp.com` and `projectname.web.app`. Firebase can auto-create those domains for you, as it owns the `firebaseapp.com` and `web.app` domains. As soon as you create the project and deploy files, you can access the hosted project through those auto-generated URLs.

If you want to use your own domain name to access the hosted files, you can just register that domain with a domain registrar of your choice, and then [connect that domain to Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain).

For example, the expense-tracking app we built in our [I/O talk this year](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvbq12bGqHI) is built on a Firebase project named `z2a-expenses`. So the hosted web app is available under the auto-generated [z2a-expenses.firebaseapp.com](https://z2a-expenses.firebaseapp.com), and [z2a-expenses.web.app](https://z2a-expenses.web.app), but also under the custom domain [xpnz.io](https://xpnz.io). There are all the exact same app/project on Firebase hosting, and just different URLs pointing to that project. So in the talk, you'll only see us sharing the `xpnz.io` URL as that how we want our users to reach the app.

Comment: Thanks so much @Frank van Puffelen..it's making sense to me now.